# Date Format conversion inaccurate results in oracle

Tags: oracle

```
SELECT substr(partition_name, 8, 16)
FROM all_tab_partitions
WHERE TABLE_owner IN (
        'DATAMARTCORE'
        ,'DWHCORE'
        )
    AND TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(substr(partition_name, 8, 16), 'yyyy/mm/dd'), 'yyyy/mm/dd') <= to_char(to_date('2015/05/31', 'yyyy/mm/dd'))
```

The following query results in error - literal does not match format string

Want all partitions that are less than may

Partition_name column is in string format

Comment: As a general rule, it's very difficult to get date calculations right if you use strings. It's like trying to do a multiplication with words: `'three' * 'five'`.

Comment: `to_char(to_date('2015/05/31', 'yyyy/mm/dd'))` makes no sense whatsoever. It's a complicated and useless way to write `'2015/05/31'` and `TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(substr(partition_name, 8, 16), 'yyyy/mm/dd')` can be replaced with just `substr(partition_name, 8, 16)` as well. The whole expression can be simplified to `substr(partition_name, 8, 16) = '2015/05/31'`

Comment: do all the partition names have the same format - including the catchall partitions?

Comment: please add a sample of the values in partition_name column.

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions162.htm) substr has the following specification:

```
SUBSTR(string, position, substring_length)
```

*Note: position is 1-based  (but if you put 0 it will imply 1)*

So a substring length of 16 won't fit into "yyyy/mm/dd" which may explain the error message.

Furthermore I can't see any point in comparing dates by converting to strings where comparing dates would be sufficient.

So I have updated your SQL as:

```
SELECT substr(partition_name, 8, 16)
FROM all_tab_partitions
WHERE TABLE_owner IN ( 'DATAMARTCORE' ,'DWHCORE')
AND TO_DATE(substr(partition_name, 8, 10), 'yyyy/mm/dd') <= to_date('2015/05/31', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
```

Comment: Thanks Richard for a quick response, I am getting the following error after running the query

Comment: sample records  select  substr(partition_name, 8, 16) from all_tab_partitions
 SUBSTR(PARTITION_NAME,8,16)

20140403
20140131
20150212
  select  TO_DATE(substr(partition_name, 8, 8), 'yyyy/mm/dd') from all_tab_partitionsTO_DATE(SUBSTR(PARTITION_NAME,8,8),'YYYY/MM/DD')

03/04/2014
31/01/2014

Comment: That's the incorrect date format.   yyyy/mm/dd = "2014/04/03"  ( note the slashes ).   You need to use date format "yyyymmdd" in your query.

Comment: Hi Richard, still it's resulting in an date issue, not a valid month  SELECT substr(partition_name, 8, 8)
FROM all_tab_partitions
WHERE TABLE_owner IN ( 'DATAMARTCORE' ,'DWHCORE')
AND TO_DATE(substr(partition_name, 8, 8), 'yyyymmdd') <= to_date('31/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy')

Comment: Richard, is this correct  SELECT TO_DATE(substr(partition_name, 8, 8), 'YYYYMMDD')
FROM all_tab_partitions
WHERE TABLE_owner IN ( 'DATAMARTCORE' ,'DWHCORE')
AND TO_DATE(substr(partition_name, 8, 8), 'YYYYMMDD') <= to_date('20150101', 'YYYYMMDD')

Comment: yes its correct.   I've done a test - see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3eeaf/2  .   I think there might be an inconsistency in your partition_name data - if there is any record which doesn't meet that you will get an date format error.

Comment: SELECT substr(partition_name, 8, 8) FROM 
all_tab_partitions WHERE 
TABLE_name='DWFD_SALDOS'
SUBSTR(PARTITION_NAME,8,8)

22012123
22013030
22013030



SELECT substr(partition_name, 8, 8) FROM 
all_tab_partitions WHERE 
TABLE_name='DWFD_SALDOS'
AND TO_DATE(substr(partition_name, 8, 8), 'YYYYMMDD') <= to_date('31/05/2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY') 

ORA-01843: not a valid monthThanks Richard, still struggling with the same issue

Comment: see my previous comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot Richard, I have worked it out, was an issue with the substr that i was taking SELECT substr(partition_name, 9, 8) FROM all_tab_partitions WHERE TABLE_name='DWFD_SALDOS' AND TO_DATE(substr(partition_name, 9, 8), 'YYYYMMDD') <= to_date('31/05/2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY')